What factors make a technology grow exponentially over time? (e.g., as in Moore's Law)
We all know Moore's Law, namely that computing power grows exponentially. The specific statement of Moore's Law had to do withe the doubling time (2 years) of the number of transistors in a semiconductor, but today we have generalized the concept to become a statement about the improvement of more general metrics for computing power.
There are other technologies that improve faster than linear. For example: battery performance, pixel density, gene sequencing.
Question: Is there a theory that explains (or provides a framework) for why some technologies grow faster than linearly? I am not necessarily looking for a well-established theory. Even an attempt at an explanation would be interesting.
I have done some Google search. I came across the performance curves and related papers, as well as some specific papers comparing rates of growth for different technologies. Cool, but dated and without follow up.
I have not been able to find anything recent? If you know a resource / perspective / theory / blog post that gives some good answers, please let me know. Thanks in advance. It could come from philosophy, economics, computer science, engineering.
PS: I have asked ChatGPT about this and the answers are good, but I am looking for something deeper and better established.

For chips in particular there are two things to consider. First, the industry took the concept and institutionalized it with an industry roadmap dedicated to staying on Moore’s law as long as possible. It became a self-fulfilling prophecy. Two, chips are 2D, so decreasing a length (linear dimension) increases density as the square.

This is a good question. Sometimes I wonder why we aren't all driving $10 cars that get 10,000 miles to the gallon. I know the answer is that automobile technology doesn't follow Moore's Law, but why doesn't it?

You mean futurological theories like Kurzweil's "law of accelerating returns"? Prodanov surveys some common factors behind "exponential technologies" in Technological Revolutions. For a more skeptical take on driving factors and prospects of exponential growth, see Ayres, Turning point.

@JonCuster Good points about the quadratic nature of "number of transistors".

@Conifold Thanks for the links. I knew about Kurzweil's views, but I always saw it as supporting his "singularity" idea, namely that technology growths exponential until we reach a singularity. What I am looking is a reason why some technologies grow faster than linear and others don't.

Some quick thoughts. Some of these things are "miniaturization", like making transistors smaller. The underlying ideas (units of information, and elementary operations) do not have a physical scale, computationally it is the same if your bit is 1 meter or 1 micrometer big. So it is "only" successive steps of making them smaller, by some percentage every time, and the result is multiplicative increases in power every time.

Somewhat similar is perhaps "eliminating initial inefficiencies". Start with a very clumsy automobile. It probably has many separate sources of inefficiency, possibly combining multiplicatively (lose 50% of energy here in the engine, 30% of the remaining energy in the transmission etc; with whatever remains at the wheels, you are working against friction and air resistance). Start eliminating these efficiencies one by one: multiplicative gains in total efficiency -- at least for a while, until you reach some fundamental limits. These are just quick thoughts, I haven't searched for references.

Exponential growth of anything cannot continue for long time, for evident reasons. When something new appears, for which here is a large demand, and large resources, the exponential growth begins. It ends or slows down when either demand or resources are
exhausted. This applies to technology as well. When some new technology is invented, it starts growing. After some time, the growth slows down or stops.

My very simple mental model explains it like this: Transistors on a chip behave like dollars under compound interest, until physics intervenes.
In a completely idealized savings account, you put in \$100 and get 10% interest your first year. Now you have $110. You leave the money alone another year, you get 10%, now you have \$121. That extra \$1 is weird, right!? Dollars you didn't own have appeared from the dollars you did, and those new dollars have produced a very new dollar of their own. It has always felt weird, and powerful, to me.
I like to hand-wave "and transistors are the same" because this year's computing power can be directly invested in optimizing or completely rethinking next year's chip designs. Any fast computer opens the door to a faster computer than previously achievable. Rinse and repeat for a generation.
It doesn't take long for the "compound interest gains" to completely overshadow the initial investment, in dollars and transistors. When you have a technology that is capable of using all its output as next year's input directly, you have the potential for sustaining faster-than-linear growth.

Since posting my question, I have been doing more research. The idea of compounding shows up in two forms. First, the compounding over time, as you describe. Better tech helps make even better tech. A similar idea is the compounding of factors. The "aggregation of marginal gains". If the performance of a technology is the product of  7 different factors, and each of them improves by 10%, then we have a doubling in performance.
